# Script Editor in Snow Leopard painfully slow after adding apps to Library

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, applescript

I have four different Macs that I use from time to time, and on each of them I notice a constant: adding more items to AppleScript Editor's Library window slows performance of mundane operations (opening a dictionary, switching between Library window and editor window, scrolling in the Library window, etc).

In Leopard, I noticed little to no latency in opening a dictionary in Script Editor, but Snow Leopard's AppleScript Editor kills my productivity by making me wait on it with most UI interactions with the Library window.

Comment: So, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've come up with so far is to abandon the Library entirely for the menu item "Open Dictionary..." via Command-Shift-O.  This brings up a list of scriptable applications that the OS is aware of.  It defeats the purpose of the Library and it's ability to focus the current script at a given application, but then again, I never thought that the tell block was too hard to include on every script prior to Snow Leopard.

In the spirit of closing tickets, et al., I provide this answer and close my question.